# Why doesn't my input animation stop on focus as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have a continuous typed animation running on my search input placeholder (which id is #typed).

[image]

I want the animation to be stopped when I focus on the input field and that should allow me to write anything there. and also want to resume the animation when I move focus from the input field.

Can you find out where have I mistaken? Thanks in advance for the kind assistance.

```js
    <script>
         var options = new Typed("#typed", {
        strings: ["best data science courses", "best python courses", "best web development courses"],
        typeSpeed: 75,
        backSpeed: 50,
        backDelay: 800,
        startDelay: 500,
        loop: true,
        showCursor: false,
        cursorChar: "|",
        attr: null,
      });
      /* install type.js*/

      var typed = new Typed("#typed", options);
      /* input field focus in */
      $("#typed").focus(function() {
        /* stop type.js*/
        $("#typed").stop();
      });
      /* input field focus out */
      $("#typed").focusout(function() {
        /* resume type.js*/
        $("#typed").start();
      });
    </script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/2.0.10/typed.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome. Your snippet has a script error and lacks HTML. Please fix those issues. See [ask] for tips.

Comment: It would also help if you clearly identify and and a link to the `Typed` library you are using.

Comment: please take your time to edit the snippet into a working one, thanks